# Linked list constructor with node iterators giving error of invalid pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am in the process of creating my own linked list. I am attempting to create an overloaded constructor of my linked list that takes two node_iterators that point to the head and tail of another linked list.

**overloaded list constructor:**

```
template <typename T>
list<T>::list(node_iterator<T> front, node_iterator<T> back)
{
    unsigned temp;
    this->head = front.get_current();
    while(front != back)
    {
        ++temp;
        ++front;
    }
    this->tail = back.get_current();
    this->used = temp;

}
```

Above `head` and `tail` are `node<T>*` to my nodes in the list. `front` and `back` node_iterators that I have created. The `get_current()` method returns a `node<T>*` to the current node my `node_iterator` class is pointing at. I have tested my overloaded `++` and `!=` operator in my `node_iterator` class and they work. However when attempt to create my list class with the above constructor I get the following error:

`*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0xbf91b1a4 ***`

Any tips on how I can fix this or do the above in a better fashion? Please let me know if you need to see more.

Comment: Why would you ever need a constructor that takes the head and tail of another list? Those values should be private members of the class and inaccessible from the calling scope anyway.

Comment: For a start, `temp` is never initialised.

Comment: I think a straight-up debug session would tell you more than any guess work given here. Have you stepped through with a debugger?  Which line does the crash occur on?  As an aside, `temp` is uninitialized (it's not the crasher - at least not here).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart my node iterators are a separate class and are not members of my linked list class.

Comment: Also, I'm curious - are the nodes used in this constructor going to live on both lists?  How will the list destructor deal with that?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I am attempting to `step` through my program with `gdb` but it finishes executing before I can execute any commands. Is there any way I can step through before it executes?

Comment: @Nic: `gdb` finishes before you even get to `main()`?  Are you using gdb's `start` command or what?  Set a breakpoint on the first line of the problem constructor before you do `run` or `start`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for your suggestions about GDB. I have learned a lot about it and have a feeling that I will be using it ALOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp` is never initialised. I guess it should have been

```
unsigned temp = 0;
```

As a result of the missing `= 0`, `this->used` ends up being some random value. I guess some time later in the code (not actually in the constructor), this causes the crash.

Comment: This was one of many of my problems. Thank you for catching it.